# Jenkins is creating one more .jenkins folder under my username

Tags: jenkins

I had a jenkins windows server and suddenly it stopped working.(localhost:8080 not working) I used "java -jar jenkins.war" command in jenkins directory but it installed a new jenkins under my username without the existing jobs and plugins.
I want the previous jenkins with all the jobs/plugins and configurations as I have the directory but can not access the jenkins UI.

Answer (score 0):

When starting Jenkins is looking for environment variable `$JENKINS_HOME`. 
When undefined it will default to create `$HOME/.jenkins` (Linux) `%HOMEPATH%/.jenkins` (Windows) folder as the home.

You can set the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME=<desired path>`

For example:

```
set JENKINS_HOME=D:\Jenkins
```